# How to set child under parent in Firebase RealTime database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a unique number generator. when i generate them and click on button I want then the unique number save in my realtime database under a parent name All_Chassis which is already available there. but the code not set the details in my Firebase realtime database

My database structure is like this.

```js
{
  All_Chassis{
    chassis{
      Model:Model_name 
    }
  }
}
```

I try like this but it is not working

```js
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "*********************",
  authDomain: "***************************",
  databaseURL: "************************",
  projectId: "*********************",
  storageBucket: "***************",
  messagingSenderId: "**************",
  appId: "******************",
  measurementId: "*****************"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();
var app = firebase.database();
var deviceref = app.ref('/All_Chassis/');
let chassis = ""

function getOption() {

  /**-------------------------------Random Number Genrator-----------------------------------**/

  var ts = String(new Date().getTime()),
    i = 0,
    out = '';

  for (i = 0; i < ts.length; i += 3) {
    out += Number(ts.substr(i, 2)).toString(36);
  }

  var ans = Math.random().toString(15).slice(5);
  var para = (out + ans);

  var chassis = (para.slice(0, 15));
  console.log(chassis);
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = chassis;
  /**-------------------------------Random Number Genrator-----------------------------------**/

  app.ref(chassis).set({
    Model: Model
  });
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @AlexMamo it's not set the the chassis and model in database you can see in the last lines of the code

Comment: Steps to debug this: 1) `console.log(chassis, Model)` right before the call to `set()` and check if their value matches what you expect. 2) Try a simpler write operation like `app.ref('test').set(true)`. If that *does* work, you know the problem is in the data you try to write. If that *does not* work, you know the problem is unrelated to the values, and is more likely in the connection to the database.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen by using app.ref('test').set(true) i can see the value `test:true` in my realtime database and i can also see the same value in my console right before set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the solution.
I have to set like this for getting the value in Firebase realtime database

```js
    app.ref('/All_Chassis/'+chassis).set({
      Model:Model.value
    
    

  })
```